# Keep getting "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, comparison

```
data_df.loc[data_df['hotelID'] == sqlIDs[neededId] & to_integer(df.iloc[row, 6]) >= to_integer(MostRecent)]
```

This is the snippet that keeps getting me that error. The `'df.iloc[row, 6]'` is a date and so is `'MostRecent'`. I convert them to integers because if I don't it gives me a separate error

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'int' and 'Timestamp'

The `'data_df['hotelID']'` is an int comparing to another int `'sqlIDs[neededId]'`

So the whole point of this line is to find only rows with both the matching int (referred to as the `neededId`) and a date that is greater than the `MostRecent`

Comment: first, use brackets for grouping; second, what is `to_integer`. also clarify exactly which error you are getting: series ambiguous or unsupported operand?

Comment: to_integer is to convert the date to an integer value to compare one another. And its series ambiguous

Comment: Actaully, being more specific with the bracets did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Brackets around each needed specification: `data_df.loc[(data_df['hotelID'] == sqlIDs[neededId]) & (to_integer(df.iloc[row, 6]) >= to_integer(MostRecent))])`